# How to use Catalog rule "Conditions_serialized" to validate product attribute?

Tags: magento2, catalog

I have define a condition the which product as product attribute "Hot" equal to "yes" on my table "product_label".

How to use \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition... to validate $product with my condition?

**The condition is record as following**

```
 a:7:{s:4:"type";s:48:"Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition
\Combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_
processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:0;a:5:
{s:4:"type";s:48:"Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition
\Product";s:9:"attribute";s:7:"hkt_hot";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";
s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}}}
```

Thanks
Norman

Answer (score 0):

Without coding you can make this check using the system already in place:

Your "hot" attribute property **is_used_for_promo_rules** must be set to 1.

Additionally, the function [Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::isAllowedForRuleCondition()](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Attribute.php#L282) sets the following prerequisites:

An attribute must be visible (attribute property **is_visible** must be equal 1).
The **frontend_input** property must be one of the following types: ‘text’, ‘multiselect’, ‘textarea’, ‘date’, ‘datetime’, ‘select’, ‘boolean’, ‘price’.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the list of product IDs satisfying the serialized conditions.

Create model `Vendor/Module/Model/Rule.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Rule extends \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule
{

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalogrule_rule';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getRule() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';

    /**
     * Store matched product Ids
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_productIds;

    /**
     * Limitation for products collection
     *
     * @var int|array|null
     */
    protected $_productsFilter = null;

    /**
     * Store current date at "Y-m-d H:i:s" format
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_now;

    /**
     * Cached data of prices calculated by price rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $_priceRulesData = [];

    /**
     * Catalog rule data
     *
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_catalogRuleData;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheTypesList;

    /**
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_relatedCacheTypes;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator
     */
    protected $_resourceIterator;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory
     */
    protected $_combineFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_actionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\Rule\RuleProductProcessor;
     */
    protected $_ruleProductProcessor;

    /**
     *
     * @var Data\Condition\Converter
     */
    protected $ruleConditionConverter;

    /**
     * Rule constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $combineFactory
     * @param Rule\Action\CollectionFactory $actionCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator $resourceIterator
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\CatalogRule\Helper\Data $catalogRuleData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypesList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param Indexer\Rule\RuleProductProcessor $ruleProductProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $relatedCacheTypes
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $combineFactory, \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action\CollectionFactory $actionCollectionFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator $resourceIterator, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, \Magento\CatalogRule\Helper\Data $catalogRuleData, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypesList, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime, \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\Rule\RuleProductProcessor $ruleProductProcessor, \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null, \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null, array $relatedCacheTypes = [], array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $productCollectionFactory, $storeManager, $combineFactory, $actionCollectionFactory, $productFactory, $resourceIterator, $customerSession, $catalogRuleData, $cacheTypesList, $dateTime, $ruleProductProcessor, $resource, $resourceCollection, $relatedCacheTypes, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Init resource model and id field
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    /**
     * Getter for rule conditions collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine
     */
    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->_combineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for rule actions collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action\Collection
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->_actionCollectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function toArray(array $arrAttributes = array())
    {
        return parent::toArray($arrAttributes);
    }

    public function getListProductIds()
    {
        $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
        $this->_productIds = [];
        $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
        $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator')->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), [
            [
                $this,
                'callbackValidateProduct'
            ]
        ], [
            'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
            'product' => $productFactory->create()
        ]);
        return $this->_productIds;
    }

    /**
     * Callback function for product matching
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @return void
     */
    public function callbackValidateProduct($args)
    {
        $product = clone $args['product'];
        $product->setData($args['row']);
        $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
        foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
            $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
            if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                $this->_productIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare website map
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
        $map = [];
        $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            // Continue if website has no store to be able to create catalog rule for website without store
            if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                continue;
            }
            $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        return $map;
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you'd like to find the product IDs. Use below code snippet.

```
...
    private $ruleModel;
...

...
    private function getRuleModel()
    {
        if($this->ruleModel === null) {
            $this->ruleModel = $this->objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule');
            $this->ruleModel->setName('name')
            ->setDescription('description')
            ->setWebsiteIds($this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        }
        return $this->ruleModel;
    }

...

...
// somewhere in your method
    $matchedProductIds = $this->getRuleModel()
                ->setData('conditions_serialized', $conditions_serialized)->getListProductIds();
...
```